# Не понимаю, как работает return

Tags: python

Есть две функции. Как передать `money_of_coin` и `money_of_fiat` в функцию `prices`. Разве `return` не возвращает вычисления в данном случае? Я перечитал несколько источников, но так и не понял, как это работает.

```
def wallet_response (coin, fiat):
    responses = requests.post(url , headers=headers).json()
    for wallet in responses:
        if str(fiat.upper()) == str(wallet[2]): 
            money_of_fiat = str(wallet[2])
            return money_of_coin
        elif str(coin.upper()) == str(wallet[2]):
            money_of_coin = str(wallet[2])
            return money_of_fiat     
        else:
            continue


'''Цены для монет'''
def prices(coin, fiat):
    symbol = str(coin) + str(fiat)
    responses = requests.get('https://api.kuna.io/v3/tickers?symbols=' + str(symbol)).json()
    for response in responses:
        bid_price = response[1]
        ask_price = response[3]
    wallet_response(coin, fiat)
    print(money_of_fiat)
    print(money_of_coin)
prices('btc', 'rub')
```

Comment: замените 
`wallet_response(coin, fiat)` на 
`result_wallet_response = wallet_response(coin, fiat); print(result_wallet_response)`

Comment: Передал `None`.

Comment: поставьте принты в функции `wallet_response ` перед `return'ами`, чтобы увидеть какие значения вы возвращаете.

Comment: Да, return возвращает вычисления (значения), нужно присвоить результат возвращаемый функцией wallet_response переменной и вывести его с помощью print()

Comment: Ок, переформулировал вопрос.

Comment: Куда по-вашему возвращает return?